# Varchar2(20 Byte) column holds more data then allowed

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I have a column `x VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)`

When inserting data with size>20 bytes it works ok.

Is this how it should work? Would expect an error in this case. Also characters were converted from `♫ -> ¿`

```
UPDATE "table" 
    SET x = '¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿☼☼☼☼☼☼☼' 
WHERE xxx = 'xxx' 
  AND yyy = 'yyy'
```

Commit Successful

Comment: There are only 19 characters in your sample query

Comment: Yes, but the byte size was 2 bytes / character. ♫ is 3 bytes in UTF - 8 anyway found out that the DB uses another type of character-set.

Comment: Well apparently the input value was converted from a multi-byte character set to a single byte character set - that's why an allegedly longer value it fits into a `varchar(20 byte)` column. Check your application how it accepts the values and how it sends them to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that charcter set is WE8MSWIN1252 by using query

SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' ;

And this is the reason for allowing the input of the characters as WE8MSWIN1252 is a single byte character set.

Comment: But Windows 1252 does not support `☼` either.

Comment: Indeed, seems that one was converted to ¤ in the column.